# How to use an API webhook in React to receive notifictions

Tags: reactjs, webhooks, github-webhook

This is my first time working with Webhooks and I was wondering if it was possible to receive notifcations from a Webhooks subscription. I'm using create-react-app for my project and want to use github's Webhooks subscription to send an alert everytime I commit to my github repository. How would I tackle this project and what would I need to do to test my Webhooks subscription?

Answer (score 9):

I hope this tip helps! Let's get to it ...

I suggest using a web socket, where your application will be listening to the back end.

This will prevent you from creating request loops for the backend.

**Additional information...**

> React only consumes information, who provides and controls is only the
> backend.

Hope this helps. Success!

```
class Main extends Component {
    ......
    // instance of websocket connection as a class property
    ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3000/ws')
    componentDidMount() {
        this.ws.onopen = () => {
        // on connecting, do nothing but log it to the console
        console.log('connected')
        }
        this.ws.onmessage = evt => {
        // listen to data sent from the websocket server
        const message = JSON.parse(evt.data)
        this.setState({dataFromServer: message})
        console.log(message)
        }
        this.ws.onclose = () => {
        console.log('disconnected')
        // automatically try to reconnect on connection loss
        }
    }
    render(){
        <ChildComponent websocket={this.ws} />
    }
}
```

> In the example I used a class component. A tip to take advantage of
> modern features would be to start with functional components.

**UPDATE 2023**

It's been a few years since this topic was answered, I see that there are still people with related questions. I will add a basic update to functional components that is more modern than the old class components.

```
export const MyFunctionalComponent = () => {

  const handleWebSocket = () => {
    const newSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/ws");
    newSocket.onopen = () => console.log('WS Connected');
    newSocket.onclose = () => console.log('WS Disconnected');
    newSocket.onerror = (err) => console.log("WS Error");
    newSocket.onmessage = (e) => {
      const data = JSON.parse(e.data);
      console.log("WS Receives: ", data);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => { 
    handleWebSocket();
  }, []);
}
```

Success on your development journey!

Comment: Is a 2023 version with React Hooks available?

Comment: This is my functional components version of websocket:    useEffect(() => {
        const newSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/ws")
        newSocket.onopen = () => console.log('connected');

        newSocket.onclose = () => console.log('disconnected');

        newSocket.onerror = (err) => console.log("ws error");

        newSocket.onmessage = (e) => {
            const msgObj = JSON.parse(e.data);
            console.log("ws receives msgObj: ", msgObj);
            ...
        return () => {
            newSocket.close();
        };
    }, []);

Answer (score 0):

Not answering the op's question, I just want to provide my functional component version of websocket to complement the answer above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61789517/4417296:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const newSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/ws")
    newSocket.onopen = () => console.log('connected');

    newSocket.onclose = () => console.log('disconnected');

    newSocket.onerror = (err) => console.log("ws error");

    newSocket.onmessage = (e) => {
        const msgObj = JSON.parse(e.data);
        console.log("ws receives msgObj: ", msgObj);
        ...

    return () => {
        newSocket.close();
    };
}, []);
```