# Receive data on front-end React app from webhook

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, webhooks, strapi

I am building a headless CMS with Strapi. I am testing the webhooks section and want to show the received data from the webhook on my React front-end.

I created a new folder `webhooks` on my local machine and ran `npm init -y`.
It created a `package.json` file with this content in it:

```
{
  "name": "webhooks",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2"
  }
}
```

I added a `index.js` file to the root folder with this content and installed `express` and `body-parser`:

```
const express = require("express")
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")

const app = express()
const PORT = 3001

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.post("/webhook", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body)
  res.status(200).end()
})

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(` Server running on port ${PORT}`))
```

After that I added this line in my `package.json`:

```
"start": "node index.js"
```

So it will start up with `npm start` instead of `node index.js`.

I added this URL to my strapi webhooks: `http://localhost:3001/webhook` and tested the trigger from the Strapi admin. It works fine.

After this I ran `npx create-react-app client` to create my react front-end app.

My next question is now how can I receive the contents from the webhook in my react front-end app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am trying to do the same thing and I found that you need to basically use web sockets to establish a two way connection between your front-end and back-end. This way, when the back-end receives the notification, it will then notify your front-end.

Similar SO question with a good answer with some code:
[How to use an API webhook in React to receive notifictions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61789285/4543112)

Note, it shows how to listen to an event on the front-end using standard JS but you could use a library like [Socket IO](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/). This guide is really good for using [SocketIO with a React app](https://socket.io/how-to/use-with-react).To trigger the event from the server, you can use the same library and `emit` an event after doing the console.log in the `/webhook` route. Just take a look at the Socket IO docs, it's pretty simple.

In the [Broadcasting](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/#broadcasting) section, they show how to broadcast from the server to all connected clients:

```
io.emit('yourEventName', { someProperty: 'some value', otherProperty: 'other value' }); // This will emit the event to all connected sockets
```

On the client, after importing `socket.io.js` you can:

```
var socket = io();

socket.on('yourEventName', function(msg) {
console.log(msg);
});
```

For **Vercel** users: you can listen to a websocket but you cannot be the websocket server, you can google it, so you need an alternative solution that handles websockets for you like PubNub or Pusher, or change hosting.