# React webhook support to avoid polling model?

Tags: reactjs, webhooks

I’m curious what’s the best way to support web hooks in React?

Suppose you build a web app and there’s a notification icon. The icon changes colors when notifications are present.

The easiest solution is a polling model where React asks for updates every x seconds… But if every user is submitting redundant requests, this is cost prohibitive.

A web hook on the other hand, should allow an enduring connection between the frontend and backend for notifications to be shared with frontend.

Suppose you’re using AWS, SNS should be able to send notifications to React. But a connection would need to already exist - hence my interest in web hooks.

A dated answer using class based react (rather than hooks) suggests using web sockets rather than web hooks.

But I’d like to know

1. If react does / doesn’t support web hooks
2. If not, what’s the current React hook based work around? (Ex still using web sockets)

[How to use an API webhook in React to receive notifictions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61789285/how-to-use-an-api-webhook-in-react-to-receive-notifictions)

Comment: There are many problems with this question. First WebHooks are for servers, what you want are WebSockets. Second your goal is to use AWS SNS, but that service does not support pushing to browsers; If you want to use AWS SNS you would have to set it to push to your server and your server should push those notifications over WebSockets.     Lastly you are mixing React and JavaScript; React's only job is rendering your HTML, JavaScript is the thing that receives notifications and notifications aren't even shown though React, so there is nothing React should do here.

Comment: @zoran404 I see that web hooks are loosely defined as “ The term webhook generally means posting an event to another system over the web through an API” by https://www.techtarget.com/searchapparchitecture/tip/Webhooks-explained-simply-and-how-they-differ-from-an-API#:~:text=The%20term%20webhook%20generally%20means,using%20SMS%20or%20SMTP%20events. which is aligned with your comment. Sounds like SNS performs the web hook functionality (server to server comms) and interaction w/ frontend is indeed handled separately.